# Is there a way to use org-mode TODO settings in another major mode? e.g. Markdown?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Is there a way to use org-mode TODO settings in another major mode? For example, is there a way to get a Markdown file I'm working on to have TODOs listed in it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of org-mode logic being applied to other markup formats like markdown.  It definitely is an intriguing possibility.

If you find markdown necessary, you could convert markdown to org-mode syntax and back.  [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) can convert from markdown to org-mode.

```
pandoc -f markdown -t org project-notes.md
```

You can then export from org-mode to markdown using `C-c C-e m`.  You would probably need to tweak the process heavily to avoid thrashing of artifacts between converters since the conversion back and forth is far from perfect.

Personally, I would choose to use an org-mode file as an authoritative copy and export from that as needed since it is more powerful.